# Does Catholicism allow rebaptism?

Tags: catholicism, baptism

I'm Catholic and have made all my sacraments.  I'm going to Israel and am interested in being baptized in the Jordan River.  Is this allowed?

Comment: The second baptism is invalid.

Comment: You can always cleanse yourself in the Jordan.

Comment: Yes, nobody is stopping you getting immersed or sprinkled in the Jordan as long as you don't call it being baptized (at least in front of your priest).

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot be baptized twice.  The sacrament is unique and irremovable, and there is therefore no need for a second baptism.  According to the Code of Canon Law only unbaptized individuals are eligible for baptism:

> [Can. 864](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/ENG0017/_P2W.HTM) Every unbaptised person, and only such a person, can be baptised.

The Catechism of the Catholic Church also quotes this canon directly:

> [1246](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c1a1.htm) "Every person not yet baptized and only such a person is able to be baptized."46

If it is uncertain whether someone was baptized the Church may perform what is called a "[conditional baptism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_baptism)," but this is very different from a second baptism such as you desire.

Comment: That said, a sort of non-sacramental ritual cleansing may be permitted during your time in Israel.  I would ask your pastor.